How to get ACF field to show up on all posts on front end?
I have thousands of posts with attached files. These attached files are part of Advanced Custom Fields Pro. However, they are not showing on the front end for the posts.
These files are utilizing the Repeater field and the Form subfield in ACF (see image attached).
I saw in the ACF documentation to add the snippet of code and I added the basic loop and replaced the fields with the field names ('repeater_field_name'='collection-attached_documents') and ('sub_field'='attached_documents'): https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/
However my website is currently on the Twenty Twenty Four Theme and I'm only able to locate a single.html file to update all posts. I can't add this PHP code to my file as it doesn't work.
Any advice on which file to update, and if I am correctly inserting the code from the documentation so it shows up on the front end for all posts with these attached files?

You can achieve this by creating the shortcode of that PHP Code and you will be able to add that shortcode to HTML template.
